# Rest API timeout

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure AD B2C custom policies with a call to a REST API as part of one of our technical profiles validation. It works fine when response times are short enough. However, if we are adding business logic inside our REST API (adding a user to database and other steps), the method call could be taking more than 20s (for instance when the server is not warmed up).

In this case, it seems that Azure AD B2C is retrying the call to the API multiple times which does not work for us...

Would it be possible to change this behavior ? (for instance in the custom policy itself or in the REST API code)

Comment: How long does the business logic run for when the backend server is warmed-up? Do you return any additional claims from the REST API that are used by the custom policy?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett the business logic could take between 20 and 30s and we dont return any additional claims. However we would still like to notify the user that something went wrong during registration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not currently a setting to override this and I have not heard of any plans to introduce one. I recommend you use some sort of middleware such as an Azure Service Bus to receive a message once the user logs in, then later process your business logic on a schedule or in the background.

Comment: Yes indeed, I am modifying my sign up flow to complete the execution of the business logic  post login. Thx!